# Get month from datetime.datetime field in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to get the day from a datetime.datetime field in sqlalchemy defined in the model. I am sending the value from the FE to insert the data in the db. However, there is an additional field which needs only the month from that datetime.datetime field.

How could I get just the day from the value received?

Imagine I get this from the FE:

```
'occurrence_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 5, 0, 0), 
'occurrence_description': 'Occurrence description'
```

Then, in the model there is an additional field:

```
'occurrence_month': db.Column(db.Integer)
'occurrence_timestamp' = db.Column(db.DateTime)
'occurrence_description' = db.Column(db.String)
```

So, I need something like this:

```
'occurrence_month' = db.Column(db.Integer, default=getMonth())
```

where getMonth() is defined as:

```
def getMonth(occurrence_timestamp):
    return sqlalchemy.func.year(occurrence_timestamp)
```

What is the way to get the month from db.DateTime field?

I do not understand why calling directly month over the occurrence_timestamp is causing an error `AttributeError: Neither 'Column' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'month'`. For instance, having value of `'occurrence_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 5, 0, 0)` and getting the month should be the same as the following:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> var1 = datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 5, 0, 0)
>>> print(var1)
2022-01-05 00:00:00
>>> var_month = var1.month
>>> print(var_month)
1
```

However, occurrence_timestamp.month does not work. What is the difference?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming it is a valid datetime object, just calling obj.month would work.

Comment: Thanks @pypalms, getting the following: `AttributeError: Neither 'Column' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'month'`

Comment: I think there are 2 things that need to be identified. The occurrence_month, if only requiring the integer value 1-12, should be a db.Integer and not DateTime. The datetime reference will store an entire datetime.datetime object, which would require adjustment anyways. It might just make sense to instead have a constructor return that takes the occurrence_timestamp and just returns it wrapped as obj.month instead.

Comment: Sorry @pypalms, the first observation was my bad when typing the question, it is Integer type. The second one, I have the following function which replaces the previous getMonth function : `def getMonth(occurrence_timestamp): return occurrence_timestamp.month`